# 7 Watt CFL Socket -- is there a specific tool to close these copper prongs on wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, socket, cfl

[image: taped wires on opposite sides]Having spent a lot of time getting the right parts, I don't want to blow this up by not connecting it properly.  Please see picture and tell me, is there a specific tool to close the wire connection?  I am not getting a convincing closure on my own...[image]

Now, I understand from JStewart's comment that the bulb's pins fit in the copper clamps. (Thank you!) However, I do not know what to do with the wires...  Here is a photo of the flip/under side.  Should I use quick connects to attach the wire to the circular inserts on the under side?  How do I decide which location to connect each wire to - above specs or below specs...one wire is smooth with 600V printed on it (hot?) and the other has a slight groove (neutral?)..
[image]

@JimStewart
@Harper - Reinstate Monica
One of the connections was snug, the other wire's housing was too thick so I whittled down the housing a bit to make that side fit.  Then, used some electrical tape to further secure both sides.  It turned on.

Comment: I don't think the (tinned stranded) wire connects by fitting inside those brass (copper colored) prongs. Even if you could crimp the prongs onto the wire, it would not be reliable. What country is this? The brass prongs must be intended to accept pins on the bulb. The wires to this socket must connect via screws at places not visible in your image. Note that you are supposed to connect the hot wire and the neutral in a certain way.

Comment: Can you post photos of the other side of the socket in your picture? (Like, flip it over)

Comment: The 6g44 socket is for a twist lock did you disassemble the socket? I have not seen one open like that. And I have never had to “tweak” pins in any lamp holder.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The flip side photo is included now showing the other side of the socket

Comment: @EdBeal Not clear why this base is stamped 6g44 -- I ordered a G23 base to replace the previous/original one (clip broke off of it).  When I took the lamp apart to remove the broken G23 base, I pulled these two wires out of its predecessors' brass prongs.

Comment: @MsHumBird -- the 6G44 is a control code assigned by UL

Answer (score 3):

The 2 holes touching, that look like a figure-8, on the side with the writing... are stab connections.  You just stick a right-sized wire in the hole.

The right size is typically 18 AWG solid or tinned.

Hot and neutral don't apply here.  These wires need to come off the fluorescent ballast and must be wired according to the ballast diagram.

Comment: It appears the silver colored metal in the center is only a clamp to grip the lamp base, i.e., not an electrical  contact. Also it appears the bulb is unpolarized, because it appears the bulb can be inserted two ways 180 deg rotated. If so, it does not matter which contact the hot wire goes to. The other wire is inserted on the OPPOSITE side, not adjacent. The twinned contacts must be to allow connecting to additional bases in a fixture.

Comment: @JimStewart Clarified.